# Get the remote python version with fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am new to Fabric, and so far I am able to use all the basic functionality, connect and execute bash commands. But I am trying to execute python commands too to verify the running version and other things.

but as far as the version goes, how can I get the remote python version with fab.

UPDATE (Error details):
Here is the output I got

```
[192.168.3.139] run: python --version
[192.168.3.139] out: Python 2.7.1+
[192.168.3.139] out: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mo/Projects/mazban/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 723, in main
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mo/Projects/mazban/mazban/fabfile.py", line 203, in firstrun
    version = run("python --version").split()[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
Disconnecting from 192.168.3.139... done.
```

Comment: Since this appears in Google, I'll add that you want to always "print" the output of Fabric.

If your code were "version = run("echo 'hello'") then note version would be a dictionary (not string!) which is indexed by remote host name, IP address in your case. So you'd want to try something like:
  version = run("python --version")
  print version['192.168.3.139']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the easiest solution:

```
version = run("python --version").split()[2]
```

Note: on my system, the first line of output is "BASHRC", which is why you need to do `[2]`.

Comment: What is the error? I ran that exact code through fabric on my local system and it worked. Do you have some outputting settings changed? Apparently, your `run()` does not return stdout's contents.

Comment: here is the error am getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mo/Projects/mazban/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 723, in main
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mo/Projects/mazban/mazban/fabfile.py", line 203, in firstrun
    version = run("python --version").split()[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It's not `split()` raising the error, but the subscript operator (`[ ]`) raising the error. Try using `[1]` instead. This is what I had initially, and I was suprised to find that my system would output the line `BASHRC` at the very beginning. I don't know what causes it.